# Javascript new Date(number) but produced different timezone (Malaysia)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webkit

Important notes:

1. The machine's date & time setting is the automatic setting
2. The machine is located in Malaysia, and the timezone is GMT +8
3. Malaysia do not have daylight saving

Question:

When using the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) with the number value which representing the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.
These two numbers (`378000000000`, `379000000000`) are giving different timezone.

[image: output example]

This was tested in both Chrome devtool console and node.js, they're giving the same result. Came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479) but it doesn't seems relevant.

Any clue / explanation please?

Below is the quick snippet and the screenshot of result
[image]

```js
console.log(new Date(378000000000).toString());
console.log(new Date(378000000000).toLocaleString());
console.log('-----------');
console.log(new Date(379000000000).toString());
console.log(new Date(379000000000).toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Googled "malaysia timezone change in 1982" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Malaysia - it's amazing what you can find on the "internets" :p

Comment: Ok! this makes much sense, thanks Jaromanda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jaromanda X! Learnt new history of my own country.
Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Malaysia

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `getTimezoneOffset()` method. For example:

```
const melissaBirthdayParty = new Date();
let birthdayPartyTime = melissaBirthdayParty.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log("The party is at " + birthdayPartyTime)
```